# GeoIP function returning 0

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind, mbstring

I'm working on implementing some `geoIP` functionality to redirect a user away from my .com site to the relevant country domain (.fr, .es, .co.uk ...etc).

I've the following in my `index.php` to check the users IP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

if($country_code == 'ES')
{
        header('Location: https://www.testsite.es');
}
elseif($country_code == 'GB')
{
        header('Location: https://www.testsite.co.uk');
}
elseif($country_code == 'FR')
{
        header('Location: https://www.testsite.fr');
}
else {
        header('Location: https://www.testsite.com/home');
}
```

When I check the `$country_code` variable it is an empty String and as a result the above fails and I always hit `https://www.testsite.com/home`...

I started delving into the code and noticed that first I call this method:

```
function geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $addr) {

    if ($gi->databaseType == GEOIP_CITY_EDITION_REV1) {
        $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $addr);
        if ($record !== false) {
            return $record->country_code;
        }
    } else {
        $country_id = geoip_country_id_by_addr($gi, $addr);

        if ($country_id !== false) {
            return $gi->GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODES[$country_id];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

which calls:

```
function geoip_country_id_by_addr($gi, $addr) {
    $ipnum = ip2long($addr);
    return _geoip_seek_country($gi, $ipnum) - GEOIP_COUNTRY_BEGIN;
}
```

I can't figure out why it keeps failing and returning a '0'? I am using Maxminds geoip.inc php to check the country code.

I've checked that `mbstring` is enabled within my php.ini file and it is. For some reason it just doesn't find the Country code based on the IP I pass to it. Does anyone have any help in terms of what might be causing this?

Comment: Not every IP address is associated with a location (and the location returned by any geoip service is an educated guess at best). Is this happening with all the addresses you are passing in?

Comment: Yes every single one, I've even tried with my own IP address which I know worked in the past when I used php geo IP with `PECL`. Of course you might say why don't I just use that way but I'm unfortunately unable to go down that route.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to say that I've resolved the issue. A mistake on my part and probably a sign that I need a break!

Within `geoip.inc.php` supplied by Maxmind I was initially getting these errors:

Cannot redeclare geoip_country_code_by_name() in geoip.inc on line 438

In order to fix this I simply check if the method is defined and if not I use it as follows:

```
if (!function_exists('geoip_country_code_by_name')) {
    function geoip_country_code_by_name($gi, $name) {
        $country_id = geoip_country_id_by_name($gi, $name);
        if ($country_id !== false) {
            return $gi->GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODES[$country_id];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I unfortunately had  a minor typo in the above code which prevented the code from executing properly hence returing 0 each and every time.